# Update A List of Objects Attribute with Other List using LINQ

Tags: linq, list

I have these two lists

```
var amountList = (from i in outstandingsList
                  join f in accountablesList
                       on i.Contract equals f.Contract
                  select f.Amount).ToList();

var commonContractsList = (from i in outstandingsList
                           join f in accountablesDdrsList
                                on i.Contract equals f.Contract
                           select i).ToList();
```

List amountlist gets the amounts of accountablesList for all common contracts in accountablesList and outstandingsList.

List commonContractsList gets all the contracts in common in outstandingsList and accountablesDdrsList.

What I want is to update amount in commonContractsList with all the amounts in amountlist with contract as the key.

I was trying to do a foreach, but I can't seem to get the order of actions right.

Any ideas?
Tks in advance.
Rui Martins

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the below code..You can add f.Contract in first Linq Query,Then use that one while looping to search through the other Entities to get the Value and then assign the value..

```
var amountList =(
                 from i in outstandingsList
                 join f in accountablesList
                    on i.Contract equals f.Contract
                 select f.Amount,f.Contract).ToList();  

var commonContractsList = (from i in outstandingsList
                           join f in accountablesDdrsList
                             on i.Contract equals f.Contract
                           select i).ToList();

foreach(var contract in commonContractsList)
{
   var amount=amountList.Where(o=>o.Contract==contract.Contract).Select(o=>o.Amount);
   contract.Amount=amount;
}
```

Comment: That's all it took. Tks a lot.